# CMS для Java

Tags: apache, java, cms, tomcat

Может я неправильно выразился, меня интересует система управления содержимым для Apache Tomcat. Или, подскажите, в какой программе можно накидать компонентов для веб-страничек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems